# Angular2 2.0.1 component unit test with core Injector

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I'm dynamically creating components using ComponentFactoryResolver and also dynamically passing them inputs using the ReflectiveInjector.

This looks about like

```
@ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;
let inputProviders = [{
    provide: 'injectedInput',
    useValue: inputValue
}];
let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.container.parentInjector);
let factory = componentInfo.factory.resolveComponentFactory(componentInfo.component);
let component = factory.create(injector);
this.container.insert(component.hostView);
```

Then the dynamically created component looks like this

```
import {Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';  
@Component({
    selector: 'mycomponent'
})
export class MyComponent {
    private id: string;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        this.id = injector.get('injectedInput');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write unit tests for that component that uses the core Injector module. I'm getting the following error:

> Error: No provider for injectedInput!

My spec file look like this:

```
import { MyComponent } from 'here';
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                MyComponent
            ]
        });
    });

    let component: MyComponent;

    beforeEach(inject([RigTransferSpeedPeriodComponent], _component => {
        component = _component;
    }));

    {...my tests...}
});
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff and searched everywhere but could not find anyone who did this before.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Philippe

Comment: don't see the point why you are doing all this ... but for me it looks like your parentInjector creates the component. So the component itself uses the parentInjector, too and the parentInjector doesn't know the injectedInput. Maybe you should describe your intention and maybe there's another way to solve it than rewire the whole injection logic

Answer (score 0):

experimented a bit with plnkr, used your problem as example ;-)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: ''
})
export class TestComponent {
  constructor(
    private injector : Injector
  ) {
    injector.get('value1');
  }
}

describe('a test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      providers: [ TestComponent ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    this.injector1 = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      {provide: 'value1', useValue: 5}
    ]);

  });

  it('inject value', () => {
    expect( this.injector1.get('value1') ).toBe(5);
  });

  describe('create component', () => {
    it('with untouched injector should throw error', () => {
      expect( () => TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent) ).toThrowError();
    })

    it('with manipulated injector', () => {
      let componentInjector = TestBed.get(Injector);
      componentInjector.parent = this.injector1;
      expect( TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent) ).toBeTruthy();
    })

    it('with injectors in the wrong order', () => {
      let componentInjector = TestBed.get(Injector);
      let combinedInjector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(this.injector1, componentInjector);
      expect( () => combinedInjector.get(TestComponent) ).toThrowError();
    })
  });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/PlUUtTOZq8bPLQ5WdAbE?p=preview

proved that it's about the order of the injectors